# Best way to input/display students grades based on existing tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently building a service in which students can log in and read messages written by teachers/admins, download files and check their grades.

Problem: I have no idea how to input their grades and how to display them.

I'll try my best to describe what I want to do.

### Teacher (Inputs Grades)

[image]

### Student (Display Grades)

[image]

I already have these tables on my MySQL databse and i'm using PHP + Boostrap.

```
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_portal        |
+-------------------------+
| Messages                |
| Students                |
| Admins                  |
| Subject                 |
| Teachers                |
| Classes                 |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Not any help, but your question reminds me of [this](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Hahaha and this comic reminded me to sanitize my database inputs!

Comment: Where's the student_grades table

Comment: I haven't created that yet because i can't figure the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a teacher panel page, give teachers' their username and password and let the teachers enter grades for each student and then upload using a form. This will automatically add grades in each students' column in the grades table in MySQl which can be seen by students when they login from their portal.

And don't expect anyone to write the whole code for you here.

Comment: I've already done that, Teachers can login, send messages/files to students.

And if you read my question you know i already know that i need to use a form to send the grades, what i'm asking is: how? how this new table with the grades need to be? How i'll display the students on the Student table on this form?

Comment: First add student's name and then you can add semester 1 followed by max number of subjects a student can take(suppose 4), then write subject's name and a column a grade for each like `Student Name | Subject1_1 | Grade1_1 | Subject1_2 | Grade1_2|...` like this till 4th sem. Then initialize with NULL, display only subject name and grades which a teacher gives. If a grade is NULL, then it is still not checked.
If a subject is NULL then the student has taken less subjects than the maximum allotted.
I hope this helps.